# App.config application settings and variables

Tags: c#, web-config, app-config

I think this will be a simple question.  I have an App.config that contains a path

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="Path" value="C:\\Test\\" />
</appSettings>
```

I want to add a couple more paths to the App.config so I don't have them hard coded in my C# windows service.  Will it work if I change this

```
string newPath = @"C:\SecondTest\" + fileName;
```

to this

```
string newPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SecondPath"] + fileName;
```

I could then create SecondPath in the App.config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will work but it would be better to [combine paths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt.aspx) like this instead of using string concatenations:

```
string newPath = Path.Combine(
    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SecondPath"], 
    fileName
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes that would work (did you try it ?).

Answer (score 0):

AppSettings works like key-value storage so it will work however you like